# How do I password-protect a Samba-shared folder that uses "force user"?

Tags: networking, permissions, password, samba

After trying various things, I've found that [this has allowed me to share an external HDD from Ubuntu to my Windows computers](http://travelinlibrarian.info/2013/05/how-to-share-an-external-usb-hard-drive-from-ubuntu-to-a-windows-network/).

Is there any way that I can add some sort of password protection to this shared folder? At the moment, my Windows computer can see and open this drive, but there doesn't seem to be any security.